# Getting a list of running Emacs timers

Tags: emacs, elisp

I've created a timer and stored a reference to it in Emacs with

```
(setq my-timer-store (run-at-time "1 min" 900 'my-func))
```

I usually execute this elisp in the morning and then stop it from running overnight by executing

```
(cancel-timer my-timer-store)
```

Unfortunately I started the timer twice (without cancelling it in between) so I no longer have a reference to the first one I started and therefore I can't cancel it. Is there a way of listing all the running timers so I can clean up the one I left running.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The timers seem to be stored in `timer-list` and `timer-idle-list`.

Comment: Is the `list-timers` deprecated in emacs?