# How to remove a function from run-with-idle-timer?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have added a `lambda()` function to `run-with-idle-timer` like this:

```
(run-with-idle-timer my-configurable-idle-time t
                 (lambda ()
                    ;;; do something
                  ) )
```

Is it possible to remove this function at a later point again from the idle timer trigger?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, [`run-with-idle-timer`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Idle-Timers.html) returns a `timer` object which you can pass to [`cancel-timer`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Timers.html).

If you did not keep the `timer` object around, you can modify `timer-idle-list` by hand.

See also [Getting a list of running Emacs timers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11670567/850781).

Answer (score 9):

I also came across a similar situation, where I wanted to kill a timer I started with:

```
(setq my-timer (run-with-timer 5 5 'my-func))
```

However,

```
(cancel-timer my-timer)
```

was not working because it said my-timer was not set (don't know why this was happening).

In addition to the method of the first poster, it can be killed with:

```
(cancel-function-timers 'my-func)
```

This cancels *all* the timers calling function 'my-func.

To kill it by altering timer-list, which I also tested, I did the following:

```
(length timer-list)  ;; I had two timers..one good, one bad
(cdr timer-list)  ;; I verified the last was the one I wanted to keep
(setq timer-list (cdr timer-list)) ;; I reset timer-list
```

Obviously, this list structure will vary, so you'll have to adjust accordingly.  Substitute "timer-idle-list" if you started your timer with (run-with-idle-timer)

This should also work if you started your timer with 'gamegrid-start-timer and 'gamegrid-kill-timer is not working, since 'gamegrid-start-timer is essentially just a wrapper for 'run-with-timer

Answer (score 1):

One more solution: if you're out of luck and can't actually cancel the timer, you can always use

```
(defvar my-timer-enabler t)
(run-with-idle-timer my-configurable-idle-time t
                    (lambda ()
                      (when my-timer-enabler
                        ;;; do something
                        )))
```

So you can disable the timer by setting `my-timer-enabler` to `nil`.  And you can later re-enable the timer by simply setting the var back to `t`.